# $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

I know $\sin(x)$ to be a periodic function with period $[0,2\pi]$ bounded by $[-1,1]$.

$\sin(x)$ keeps repeating after intervals of $2\pi.$

So as $x \to \infty$ why should this behavior change? Shouldn't the value still remain in the bounds of $[-1,1]$ but despite this why is that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}  \sin(x)$ undefined.

I'm asking this because I'm trying to understand the nature of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as $x \to 0$.What I see when I graph this is repeated oscillations as $x \to 0$.

So I guess my question is, what happens to $sin(x)$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$?

Comment: As you stated, it keeps oscillating between $-1$ and $1$ so it does not approach any particular value. There is no limit.

Comment: Review the definition of limit.  It means that the expression approaches a *single value*.  Since $\sin x$ swings back and forth between $1$ and $-1$, it does not approach a single value.

Comment: $\sin$ has no limit at $\infty$, and it's precisely for the reason you and the comments have mentioned, namely that $\sin$ oscillates indefinitely between $-1$ and $1$. If you wanted to describe its behavior as $x\to\infty$, say to someone who's never heard of the sine function but knows what functions are, you could say that it oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ periodically.

Comment: As a thought experiment (or the beginning of a rigorous proof, if you're feeling spicy), ask yourself, what is the limit? What is the number to which $\sin(x)$ eventually becomes arbitrarily close? Pick a number that you think might be the limit. When will the function become and *forever stay* closer than distance $1/4$? For example, if you think the limit is $0$, when will $\sin(x)$ stay between $0 - 1/4$ and $0 + 1/4$? Never. This disproves $0$ is the limit. See if you can see why other numbers also fail to be the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative definition of convergent limits is that for every sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_n \rightarrow \bar{a}$ then $\lim_n f(a_n) = \bar{f}$. If this holds, then there is no problem with writing $\lim_{x \rightarrow \bar{a}} f(x) = \bar{f}$.

In this case, you can see that there are multiple sequences that make this limit take multiple values. For example, you can take $a_n = 2 \pi n$, $b_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$.